# Как добавить приватную задачу в YouTrack?

Tags: youtrack

Здравствуйте. Хотим переехать с Redmine на YouTrack, но вот пока не хватает одной фичи - добавление задачи, которая была бы видна только тому кому назначена (ну и кто назначил).
Т.е. например бывают задачи, в которые надо прикрепить какие-то приватные данные. Надо, чтоб никто не видел, кроме того, кто эту задачу должен решить.

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я знаю нельзя, вот решил проверить сейчас, вывел все варианты которые доступны:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]